# Prevent visual studio from limiting the setter method to internal

Tags: c#, .net, properties, visual-studio-2015, access-modifiers

Well, I use visual studio 2015 CE, update 2.
One productivity hack I usually do is that I create empty model classes like:

```
public class PersonModel
{
}
```

and then use them in a select expression like:

```
db.People.Where(p => someCondition)
.Select(p => new PersonModel
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    //set other properties
}).ToList();
```

Then I go to the yet non-existing properties `Id` and `Name`, ... and press `Control+.` to ask visual studio to `generate property Id` for me.
All great, but it will create:

```
public int Id { get; internal set; }
```

and if I use the same method in an asp.net webapi model binding, the binding will fail **silently** and give me `Id = 0`.

So my question is: is there any option to ask VS to create public setter, i.e.:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: 2021 and Visual Studio's incessant and inflexible use of the `internal` keyword in code generation is still knee-capping the potential productivity increases.

Comment: grrrr, this needs sorting, so annoying. Does anyone know if there is an open user voice to upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is: is there any option to ask VS to create public setter, i.e.:

No, there is no way to modify the shortcut to automatically add the property with a public set.
Although your productivity hack is neat, your best bet is to create it yourself.

Comment: This is horrid they don't give you any way to change that autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by typing `prop` and press the `TAB` twice. It will require you to enter type and name for property though, won't extract it from existing one.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Still the same in Visual Studio 2017 and I use the same "productivity hack".

I recently got **Resharper** and it does use the public setter as we would expect it.