# Can I customize the "Generate property" command in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I there any way to customize the output of the `Generate property...` set of commands in Visual Studio? I mean this command that pops up when you try to use a property that does not exists yet.

[image: Example image]

90% of the time I don't want the setter to be `internal` but simply `public` so I'd prefer that to be the default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent visual studio from limiting the setter method to internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037562/prevent-visual-studio-from-limiting-the-setter-method-to-internal)